# Why does IIS 7.0 return invalid HTTP status codes?

Tags: http, iis, status

[IIS 7.0 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code) shows that IIS can return status codes (like 401.1) that do not conform to [RFC7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6) which says:

> The status-code element is a three-digit integer code giving the result of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request

Why does IIS return non-compliant status codes which are going to break compliant client implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation of the IIS documentation is wrong.

If you use a tool like Wireshark to carefully analyze the HTTP response messages generated by IIS/HTTP.sys, you will see they only contain a three-digit status code as the RFC requires.

However, it is inside IIS log files, as well as other traces/error pages that a substatus code is appended to better categorize the actual errors.

> Keep in mind IIS has been out there for decades. So if anything is non-compliant, it is less likely to identify this late.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the clarification (which wasn't clear to me from the documentation).